# wrap pandas daraframe within class

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'd like to give pandas dataframe a custom and extend it with custom methods, but still being able to use the common pandas syntax on it.

I implemented this:

```
import pandas as pd

class CustomDF():
    def __init__(self, df: pd.DataFrame):
        self.df = df

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.df, name)

    def foo(self):
        print('foo')
        return
```

the problem with the above code is that I'd like to make the following lines work:

```
a = CustomDF()
a.iloc[0,1]
a.foo()
```

but if I try to access a column of the dataframe by doing

```
print(a['column_name'])
```

I get the error "TypeError: 'CustomDF' object is not subscriptable"

Any idea on how not requiring to access .df first to get the subscription working for the super class?
Thanks!

Comment: why don't you use inheritance? `class CustomDF(pd.DataFrame): `?

Comment: unfortunately I get the error "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object"

Comment: what you really want is an extension of the class, that is, you want the new object to have the methods of `pd.DataFrame`, so the solution must be inheritance

Comment: sorry, my question was wrong. The problem is only that the class is not subscriptable with square brackets... see updated question

Comment: There's a section on extending Pandas classes in the documentation which shows various approaches to achieve what you want:  
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html

Answer (score 2):

Try inheriting from the `pandas.DataFrame` class. Like so:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

class CustomDF(DataFrame):
    def foo(self):
        print('foo')
        return
    
a = CustomDF([0,1])
a.foo()
```